# How to get/access HTTP Proxy Configuration across all jenkins project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, http-proxy

I am new on **Jenkins ver. 2.204.5**. I have set **HTTP Proxy Configuration** on my jenkins as below

[image]

When I am building my project at that time I want **HTTP Proxy Configuration** information like proxy **Server, Port, User name, Password** on **Execute Shell**. Please help me on it.

I want to HTTP Proxy Configuration on my shell to run below command:

```
npm config set proxy http://<username><password>@proxy-server-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<username><password>@proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the variables in your pipeline script like below,

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Preparation') {
    steps {
      script {
        def p = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().proxy
        env['http_proxy'] = "http://${p.name}:${p.port}"
        env['https_proxy'] = env['http_proxy']
        env['no_proxy'] = p.noProxyHost
      }
    }
  }
  stage('Build') {
    steps {
      sh 'docker build -t mms_builder_dockerrpm --build-arg http_proxy="${http_proxy}" --build-arg https_proxy="${https_proxy}" --build-arg no_proxy="${no_proxy}" .'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution Saravanan